# RREF in matlab with binary field operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to use the RREF function to get the reduced echelon form of a parity check matrix(binary) in matlab. I want the row reductions to be done under GF2. The RREF performs the operations under R. Is there anyway to fix this?

Note: for example 1+1=0 not 2, I want the resulting matrix to be 0's and 1's not in decimal form

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote a modified version of matlab's function rref, called g2rref that works great!

https://gist.github.com/esromneb/652fed46ae328b17e104